# Cannot play neither IE10 HTML5 video nor Modern UI apps video

Tags: windows-8, video, modern-ui, internet-explorer-10, html5

Since today I remarked that I couldn't play neither on-demand/live video in any Modern UI application nor HTML5 video in IE10.

Using Wireshark, I see that video URL is never called neither by the application (ISM Manifest file) nor by the browser (eg MP4). In the application, I just can see horizontal loading dots, and on [this page](http://www.w3.org/2010/05/video/mediaevents.html) in IE10, I see the picture but the video is never played; whereas it is working in Firefox. The following [page](http://www.quirksmode.org/html5/tests/video.html) displays blank areas.

I don't remember when video worked before today, as I didn't play anything in any application or browser (only Flash actually).

What can cause this behaviour? Is there a Relationship between Modern UI app and browser settings?

**EDIT**

The W3 HTML5 video test page shows:

In Firefox

```
           canPlayType
video/ogg   video/mp4   video/webm
"maybe"     "maybe"     "probably"
```

In IE10

```
           canPlayType
video/ogg   video/mp4   video/webm
""          ""          ""
```

**UPDATE**

Here is a screen capture of my problem (I clicked through samples button under the video):

[image: video/mp4 not working]

With Process Monitor, I could see some calls to Windows Media Foundation registry keys.

Is it possible to repair this component?

Comment: Are you using IE10 in MUI or desktop mode? Does watching local videos work? Especially try the same video format, or even the same video if possible. (I'd also recommend Fiddler2 over Wireshark for HTTP debugging - it's easier to use. But either works, I guess.)

Comment: I tried IE10 in MUI and desktop mode. The file http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.mp4 is successfully played in WMP when I try to browse to the URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I uninstalled the driver of my `ATI Mobility Radeon HD 3670` and removed the graphic card itself (including drivers by selecting the checkbox) in the `Device Manager`. Then, I let Windows to install its own drivers for this card.

The graphic card label now contains `WDDM v1.1`. I'm pretty sure there is a causal relationship between that, Media Foundation and MPEG-4 video playing...

Answer (score 1):

In Agreement with Velcro answer

> I uninstalled the driver of my ATI Mobility Radeon HD 3670 and removed the graphic card itself (including drivers by selecting the checkbox) in the Device Manager. Then, I let Windows to install its own drivers for this card.
>   The graphic card label now contains WDDM v1.1. I'm pretty sure there is a causal relationship between that, Media Foundation and MPEG-4 video playing...

I disabled GPU rendering in IE (Internet Options > Advanced > Accelerated graphics > Use software rendering instead of GPU rendering) and it played html5 video succesfully.