# No video in Netflix modern (metro) app on Windows 10

Tags: video, windows-10, modern-ui

I have just installed Windows 10 on my emachines E443 laptop.

- Processor: AMD E-300 APU with Radeon (tm) HD Graphics
- AMD Radeon HD 6310 Graphics
- Windows 10 Pro 64 bits pt-br (clean install, not an update)

Besides installing the OS, the only things I have done are:

- Performed Windows Update (prior to that, my screen resolution was limited to only 800 x 600). It installed the latest Adobe Catalyst drivers and now I have a 1366 x 768 display.
- Updated all apps from the Windows Store (it had only Skype preinstalled)
- Install Netflix from the app store.

When I start a video on Netflix, it only plays the audio; all I see are the subtitles and the player UI but the actual video is entirely black. Sometimes (but not always) I won't get even the audio, just a warning for error W8157-887A0001. (I can open a video file locally with the "Movies and TV Shows" native metro app, and it plays fine both windowed and maximized).

I have installed the latest Silverlight, but the issue persists.

I don't know if it is related, but I can't see HTML5 video on youtube on Microsoft Edge; the audio plays all choppy and the video gets terribly corrupted. It plays fine on Firefox 39.

Disabling hardware acceleration on IE, as suggested [on this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/616658/cannot-play-neither-ie10-html5-video-nor-modern-ui-apps-video), enables video playback on both IE and Edge, but only on IE and extremely choppy when fullscreen and more than 480p

Comment: "enables video playback on both IE and Edge, but only on IE"? **What kind of malfunctioning retard are you**?

Answer (score -2):

I assume it is your Anti-Virus shields hogging processes along with a kinda slow CPU/APU.    Make sure to turn off High Definition in your Netflix options, this will reduce the chop.

I`m having a slightly different problem in the secure link on the HDMI connections for Silverlite and FireFox. I am having a problem by loss of display connection after a few seconds of silverlite play, no problems with Microsoft Edge browser.  The problem occurred after the latest Windows 10 update on 8-4-2015.

It's just Microsoft causing issues with the other web browsers.  Use Edge for now, even though I bet you hate it as much as I do.

Comment: What anti-virus? There's no anti-virus! I only installed *exclusively* what I listed. And Netflix isn't choppy for my, it's entirely black, only audio.